# Do all weapon mods work on all weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Do all weapon mods for a class of weapons work for all weapons of that class?  For example, does the Assault Rifle Piercing Mod work on a M-37 Falcon?

If the answer is no, is there a list of all incompatible weapon mods?

Note: I think the answer is no, because I don't think the SMG Heat Sink works on the Collector SMG (as of January 5, 2013).

Answer (score 1):

They work for all non-DLC weapons at the least. I don't know about DLC/special weapons like the Collector SMG however. They may be special, but any normal gun purchased/unlocked in the main story is compatible with all weapon mods of that class.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, specific weapons don't work with mods. The Adas rifle or scorpion for example because they shoot a different type of ammo eg. Adas is phaser which already has the armor piercing ammo built into it, thus no piercing or HVB mod will work with it. The benefit to these weapons are you don't have to waste a mod to make the weapon better.